# creating button with tkinter

Tags: python, button, tkinter

I was really curious why I cannot get my `add_button` to work, 
as the window fails to come up when creating it.

```
from tkinter import *
class Calculator:

#-------------------------------------------------               
    def __init__(self, master):

        self.master = master 

        master.title("Calculator")

        self.close_button = Button(master, text = "Close", command = master.destroy)        

        Label(master, text = "First Digit").grid(row = 0)
        Label(master, text = "Second Digit").grid(row = 1)

        self.input1 = 0
        self.input2 = 0

        input1 = Entry(master)
        input2 = Entry(master)

        input1.grid(row = 0, column = 1)
        input2.grid(row = 1, column = 1)


        self.close_button.grid(row = 2, column = 0)

        self.add_buton = Button(master, text = "Add", command = self.add())
        self.add_button.grid(row = 2, column = 1)                              

        master.configure(background = 'grey')

        return 

#-------------------------------------------------

    def add(self):
            return self.input1.get() + self.input2.get()   

#-------------------------------------------------



#-------------------------------------------------
root = Tk()
calc = Calculator(root)
root.mainloop()
#-------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Try `command = self.add` instead of `command = self.add()`. You are calling the callback method and using it's result as the actual callback. Also, you are confusing `self.input1` and `input1`, and misspelled `add_button` once. Also, where does the result from the callback go?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to Stack!

I've looked through you code I've been able to do what you are asking. There were a few errors within your code:

a) you had `self.add_buton` and `self.add_button` which caused an error.

b) `self.input1 = 0` and `self.input2 = 0` are not required.

c) You were calling `self.add()` as the command and you should be calling `self.add`. When calling it as a command you do not need `()`

d)`input1 = Entry(master)` should be `self.input1 = tk.Entry(master)`

e) You should convert your input values into `int` or `float` as otherwise it will just one value onto the end of the other. (Eg, `1 + 5 = 15` whereas `int(1) + int(5) = 6`

Here is your code with the entry boxes working as they should. I have `import tkinter as tk` hence why it is `tk.Entry`

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk
class Calculator:

#-------------------------------------------------               
    def __init__(self, master):

        self.master = master 

        master.title("Calculator")

        self.close_button = Button(master, text = "Close", command = master.destroy)        

        Label(master, text = "First Digit").grid(row = 0)
        Label(master, text = "Second Digit").grid(row = 1)

        self.input1 = tk.Entry(bd=5, width=35, background='gray35', foreground='snow')
        self.input2 = tk.Entry(bd=5, width=35, background='gray35', foreground='snow')

        self.input1.grid(row = 0, column = 1)
        self.input2.grid(row = 1, column = 1)


        self.close_button.grid(row = 2, column = 0)

        self.add_button = tk.Button(master, text = "Add", command = self.add)
        self.add_button.grid(row = 2, column = 1)                              

        master.configure(background = 'grey')

        return 

#-------------------------------------------------

    def add(self):
        val = self.input1.get()
        print(val)

#-------------------------------------------------



#-------------------------------------------------
root = Tk()
calc = Calculator(root)
root.mainloop()
```

This should now work how you wanted it too. The variables within the entry can be changed to suit. You were correct in calling the value of the entry with `self.input1.get()`.

Hope this has helped.

Comment: One more thing: the input values should probably be converted to `int` or `float`, otherwise `+` will just concatenate the strings. (But you removed that part from your answer anyway)

Comment: @tobias_k Yes, I forget about that, but will add it to my answer. Thanks for reminding me.